# What does this ASP viewstate mean?

Tags: asp.net, screen-scraping, web-scraping

I'm scraping an asp.net web-form and it always sends viewstates like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEXAQUDX19QDwUNZnJtQ291cnNlSW5mbw8GblQKzmHhzYgCAw==">
```

When I decode it in the [View State decoder](http://ignatu.co.uk/ViewStateDecoder.aspx) I get this object: `System.Collections.Hashtable`.

The precise value of the __VIEWSTATE varies, but it alwasy decodes to the object `System.Collections.Hashtable`.

What's going on here?  Why does the viewstate value vary but always decode to that?

Answer (score 1):

The Page is stateless and so after each postback, it has no idea what happened before. A ViewState is often used in order to persist the information between postbacks. For example, if you selected an option and created a postback, the site might store your option in a ViewState so that your option is still selected after a postback.

What your seeing is the ViewState storing information on what controls are currently rendered on the site (a Hashtable in this case). The values stored in the table may vary, but the control seems to be present between postbacks.

You can read more on ViewStates on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448.aspx) and how/when to use them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188774.aspx).

Comment: Why is the value varying?  Is there any way to get more info on the HashTable from the client-side?

Comment: The view state may contain more than just the Hashtable. The value you see is a Base-64 encoded string and changes in the encoding could be caused by anything that is stored in the ViewState. Are there any changes going on on the website?

Comment: Yes, there are changes in the form on this page (it's a series of sequential <select>s)..  How can I see the other things that are in the viewstate?  They don't show on any decoder (base64 or viewstate specific)

Comment: The site may prevent ViewStates on particular controls (or disable it on the page and enable it just for the `Hashtable`). The site may be storing information in cookies or sessions instead, or not storing anything else besides the `Hashtable`.

Comment: How can I see what else it might be storing?

Comment: Unless it's client-side storage, it'd practically be impossible. Sessions are stored server side, so there's no access to them. You could try and see what cookies are being sent to your computer and read them (if they're not encrypted). What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The web form is a sequential series of <select>'s. I want to be able to fake the viewstate value, so that I could make the web form think I have already filled out the first 2 selects when I want to get the value for the 3rd.  I know that this could be accomplished by just using the viewstate I am sent from traversing the first 2 selects.. but I want to minimize the # of requests I make to this site, so I wouldn't have to always request the first 2 <selects> to get the 3rd every time I want to get the 3rd.

Comment: You should never touch the ViewState. So you're scraping someone elses website and you're having issues with the ViewState? Are you allowed to scrape the website? It would seem to be that you're not allowed to otherwise the website owner would provide an API for you to easily consume the data.